# Angular ui tree is not working in mozilla

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-components

[Plunker.](https://plnkr.co/edit/f4QP7gzTenvknyhuIdoA?p=preview)

The above plunker is working fine in Chrome and IE. But When comes to Mozilla Firefox it is not.

When I try to select the dropdown the page is reloading.How to stop that issue.

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="items_renderer.html">
    <div ui-tree-handle>

        <a class="btn btn-success btn-xs" data-nodrag ng-click="toggle(this)"><span class="glyphicon" ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-right': collapsed, 'glyphicon-chevron-down': !collapsed}"></span></a>
        <input type="text" style="display:none" ng-model="item.rowId">
        <input type="text" id="componentName{{$index}}" ng-style="getWidth(item.rowId)" ng-change="validateOnChange(item.componentName, 'componentName','',$index)" ng-model="item.componentName" style="width:156px;height: 23px;">
        <input type="text" id="componentIdentification{{getRowId(item.rowId)}}" ng-model="item.componentIdentification" ng-change="validateOnChange(item.componentIdentification,'componentIdentification', '',getRowId(item.rowId))" style="width:125px;height: 23px;">
        <select ng-model="item.componentType" id="componentType{{getRowId(item.rowId)}}" ng-change="validateOnChange(item.componentType, 'componentType', 'Select', getRowId(item.rowId))" style="width:102px;height: 23px;">
            <option>Select</option>
            <option ng-repeat="type in typeList" value="{{type.TYPE_ID}}">{{type.COMPONENT_TYPE}}</option>
        </select>
        <select ng-model="item.componentState" id="componentState{{getRowId(item.rowId)}}" ng-change="validateOnChange(item.componentState,'componentState', 'Select' ,getRowId(item.rowId))" style="width:122px;height: 23px;">
            <option>Select</option>
            <option ng-repeat="list in statusList" value="{{list.STATUS_ID}}">{{list.STATUS}}</option>
        </select>
        <select ng-model="item.actionId" id="actionId{{getRowId(item.rowId)}}" ng-change="validateOnChange(item.actionId, 'actionId', 'Select',getRowId(item.rowId))" style="width:103px;height: 23px;">
            <option>Select</option>
            <option ng-repeat="action in actionList" value="{{action.ACTION_ID}}">{{action.URL}}</option>
        </select>
        <select ng-model="item.actionToPerform" id="actionToPerform{{getRowId(item.rowId)}}" ng-change="validateOnChange(item.actionToPerform, 'actionToPerform', 'Select',getRowId(item.rowId))" style="width:122px;height: 23px;">
            <option>Select</option>
            <option ng-repeat="actionPerform in actiontoperformList" value="{{actionPerform.ACTIONPERFORM_ID}}">{{actionPerform.ACTION_TO_PERFORM}}</option>
        </select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by disabling the drag and drop as it is calling some internal functions hence the page is reloading.

```
<div ui-tree="options" data-drop-enabled="false" data-drag-enabled="false">
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to remove the `ng-model` from the `ui-tree-nodes` div.

change this

```
<ol ui-tree-nodes ng-model="componentList">
```

to this

```
<ol ui-tree-nodes>
```

[Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/up08Y5b0zPFWvshvkQYu?p=preview)

Comment: If I remove that ng-model then the tree structure is not coming correctly

Comment: If I keep any other ng-model then again I am getting refresh of the page in mozilla